# Bayesian Beta regression Model -- Error in jags: Invalid parent value

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I'm trying to run a Bayesian pooled model in jags through R and getting an error message

I found from people who have encountered similar problems that it could be triggered by values of the priors, negative value, log of negative, syntax errors etc. I have eliminated all of these but the error persists.

```
## just for the prediction
pred.jac <- seq(min(test.bayes$Latitude), max(test.bayes$Latitude), 10)

data = list(
  jac = test.bayes$Jaccard,
  lat = test.bayes$Latitude,
  pred.jac = pred.jac)


inits = list(
  list(alpha = 1, beta = 2.5, sigma = 50),
  list(alpha = 2, beta = 1.5, sigma = 20),
  list(alpha = 3, beta = 0.75, sigma = 10))



{
  sink("BetaPooledJAGS.R")
  cat("
      model{

      # priors
      alpha ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
      beta ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
      sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)


      # likelihood


      for (i in 1:length(jac)) {
      mu[i] <- alpha + beta * lat[i]
      a[i] <- ((1 - mu[i]) / (sigma^2) - 1 / mu[i]) * mu[i]^2
      b[i] <- alpha * (1 / mu[i] - 1)
      jac[i] ~ dbeta(a[i], b[i])


      }

      # predicted jaccard as derived quantities
      for (i in 1:length(pred.jac)) {
      mu_pred[i] <- alpha + beta * lat[i]
      mu_pred1[i] <- exp(mu_pred[i])
      }

      }

      ",fill = TRUE)
  sink()
}


n.adapt = 3000
n.update = 5000
n.iter = 5000
jm.pooled = jags.model(file="BetaPooledJAGS.R", data = data, n.adapt = n.adapt, inits = inits, n.chains = length(inits))
```

When I run the code, I get the error below:

Error in jags.model(file = "BetaPooledJAGS.R", data = data, n.adapt = n.adapt,  : Error in node jac[1] Invalid parent values

Here's the link to a subset of my data.

https://fil.email/IuwgYhKs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting negative values for `b` with those initials if lat is positive, and `b` must be > 0 in a beta distribution, in JAGS, and more generally.

E.g. using initials from `inits[[1]]`:

`mu = 1 + 2.5*lat`
 assuming `lat` is positive, then `mu > 1`

`b = 1 * (1/mu-1)`
And  `1/mu < 1` if `mu>1`, so `1/mu - 1 < 0`.

Therefore
`b = 1*-ve` so `b<0`

Comment: Thanks @Umaomamaomao. Great explanation. This is not obvious when setting the initial values. Is there a convention for avoiding this? It seems that mu cannot be greater than 1 either given beta distribution? Or it doesn't matter when it's moment matched?  The obvious way to get b > 0 is to have -ve alpha? Or what would you suggest in my case?

Comment: Initials are always tricky, I don't think there's a convention as it will always depend on your model. Usually it requires a bit of thought and a lot of trial and error. Does it work if you don't initialise? That would be easiest. If alpha and  beta are much smaller e.g. beta <0.01 (assuming lat latitude, so <= 90), and alpha sufficiently small (to be safe < 0.1) so that mu is <1, then you should be OK.

Comment: Removing the initials gave same error. I followed those recommendations for alpha and beta but the error did not go away either.  I log transformed both variables and centered them but the model gave same error. I note that because jac ranged from 0.27 - 1, it's impossible not to have a situation where b = 0, which violates b > 0. But to eliminate this as a source of the problem, I removed data where jac > 0.9 but the error is the same. Further insight would  be appreciated.

Comment: Update: the recommendation for alpha and sigma worked if sigma is also small (sigma < 0.1). However,  data ranging from 0 to 1 needs truncating, in the form y[i] ~ dbeta(a[i], b[i]) T(0.001,0.99999). So, for the part of my data that is 1, I just subtracted 0.00001 from 1 to make it less than 1. I believe this workaround could work for the lower bound (0) by doing (0 + 0.00001). Note: this approach makes sense for my data because there wouldn't be a meaningful difference btw 1 and 0.99999.